# Q: Leetcode: Find Pivot Index Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-pivot-index/

Question:

> Given an array of integers nums, write a method that returns the "pivot" index of this array.
>
> We define the pivot index as the index where the sum of the numbers to the left of the index is equal to the sum of the numbers to the right of the index.
>
> If no such index exists, we should return -1. If there are multiple pivot indexes, you should return the left-most pivot index.

My answer:

```
import java.util.HashMap; 

class Solution {
    public int pivotIndex(int[] nums) {
        int runningTotal = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> resultsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int numLength = nums.length;
        //run through backwards so leftmost index is returned
        for(int i = numLength -1; i >= 0; i-- ){    
            int neededTotal = runningTotal*2 + nums[i];
            resultsMap.put(neededTotal, i);
            runningTotal += nums[i];
        }
        Integer resultIndex = resultsMap.get(runningTotal);
        if(resultIndex == null){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return resultIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

The suggested answer on leetcode instead runs through the array to get the total sum, then runs through again to find the appropriate element - and on leetcode submission my answer comes back as slower.

<strike>However, when I've tried a quick micro-benchmark for myself, it seems as if using the hashmap, in my version, is quicker on average than running through the array twice.</strike>

I messed up the benchmark - why is my version so much slower?

Suggested leetcode answer:

```
public class ListPivot {
    public int pivotIndex(int[] nums) {
        int sum = 0, leftsum = 0;
        for (int x: nums) sum += x;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            if (leftsum == sum - leftsum - nums[i]) return i;
            leftsum += nums[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you benchmark against? When running through the list twice, did you still use a HashMap? The autoboxing of ints to Integers can have a significant performance effect.

Comment: Ah - I messed up the benchmark - I was comparing the wrong code

Comment: What's the size of the array? Using `HashMap` has quite a bit of overhead, especially if it is N size big, and uses boxed integers. Their method is really well thought out (and probably somewhere in Knuth), but I think I could do better. Calculating an intermediate result *twice* seems expensive. Besides that, there is no protection against integer overflow. The `sum` and `leftsum` variables should have been `long` types.